# only higher values from array as variable number

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with numbers and variable number:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$v = 5;
```

I need result all numbers if is higher as $v:

```
$result = ?? //array(6,7,8,9,10)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's pretty basic to write.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$v = 5;

foreach($a as $value){
    if($value > $v ){
        $new[] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
```